# Why is predict() function returning point prediction outside of function wrapper, but fitted values inside

Tags: r

`predict()` is returning the fitted values of a model if I try to put it inside a function with the code that properly transforms my variables. If I run the same block of code outside of my function wrapper, the code returns the point prediction that I'm looking for. Once the code has been run outside of the function wrapper, the user-defined function will return the point prediction that was returned by the stand-alone code block, essentially ignoring any new function inputs.

I've tried running the code block by itself (outside of the function call) and it works like I expected (returns a point prediction).

```
require(e1071)
require(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars

df_resp <- log10(df1$mpg + 1)
df_pred <- select(df1, -mpg, -cyl, -vs, -gear, -carb, -am)
df_pred_scale <- scale(df_pred, center = T, scale = T)


attr_center <- attr(df_pred_scale, 'scaled:center')
attr_scale <- attr(df_pred_scale, 'scaled:scale')

df_pred_scale <- cbind.data.frame(df_pred_scale, as.factor(df1$cyl))
colnames(df_pred_scale) <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "cyl")

df_pred <- cbind.data.frame(df_pred, as.factor(df1$cyl))
colnames(df_pred) <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "cyl")

for(i in 1:6) assign(paste0('x', i), df_pred_scale[,i])

 svr_mpg <- svm(df_resp ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6,
           epsilon = 0.1,
           gamma = 0.1,
           cost = 1,
           cross = 5)
```

This code wrapped in the function predict_mpg is meant to return a point prediction
For some reason, it actually returns the fitted values inside svr_mpg

```
predict_mpg <- function(cylinder, horsepower){

  df_test <- df_pred %>% filter(., cyl == cylinder)

  data_point <- df_test[1,]

  for(i in 1:5)  data_point[,i] <- median(df_test[,i])

  data_point$hp <- horsepower

  df_norm <- scale(data_point[,1:5], t(attr_center), t(attr_scale))
  df_set <- data.frame(df_norm, data_point[,6])
  colnames(df_set) <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "cyl")
  for(i in 1:6) assign(paste0('x', i), df_set[,i])

  predict(svr_mpg, newdata = df_set) %>% 10^. -1

}
```

Running this before the block of code below will result in the fitted
values inside svr_mpg being returned
if it's run after the block below, it will essentially ignore the inputs for horsepower and cylinder
and will instead return point prediction for the code below

```
predict_mpg(6, 250)
```

This next block of code is identical to the code in the function predict_mpg
For some reason, this code will return the point prediction that I want

```
cylinder <- 6
horsepower <- 250 

df_test <- df_pred %>% filter(., cyl == cylinder)

data_point <- df_test[1,]

for(i in 1:5)  data_point[,i] <- median(df_test[,i])

data_point$hp <- horsepower

df_norm <- scale(data_point[,1:5], t(attr_center), t(attr_scale))
df_set <- data.frame(df_norm, data_point[,6])
colnames(df_set) <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "cyl")
for(i in 1:6) assign(paste0('x', i), df_set[,i])

predict(svr_mpg, newdata = df_set) %>% 10^. -1
```

I expected the function to return one value, a point prediction, but it's actually returning the fitted values for svr_mpg

Comment: What's the idea behind this line: `for(i in 1:6) assign(paste0('x', i), df_set[,i])`?

Comment: Instead of making loose variables like `x1`, `x2` etc., run the model on a data.frame to make sure all scoping is correct and predictable. Your function is probably still grabbing the `x1` etc from the global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my version. The most important part is that I run the model on a data.frame instead of on separate variables. I'm not sure `newdata` does anything if you didn't use the `data` argument in the first place.

```
library(e1071)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars %>% 
  select(-vs, -gear, -carb, -am) %>% 
  mutate(
    mpg = log10(mpg + 1),
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-mpg, -cyl), ~scale(.)[,1])

svr_mpg <- svm(   # Gives a warning for me!
  mpg ~ .,
  df1,   
  epsilon = 0.1,
  gamma = 0.1,
  cost = 1,
  cross = 5
)

predict_mpg <- function(cylinder, horsepower){
  df_set <- df1 %>% 
    filter(cyl == cylinder) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, median) %>% 
    slice(1) %>% 
    select(-mpg) %>% 
    mutate(hp = horsepower)
  predict(svr_mpg, newdata = df_set) %>% 10^. -1
}
predict_mpg(6, 250)
```

Comment: This fixes the weird prediction issues, but I don't think you scaled the hp variable inside the function call? Regardless, I'm marking as answered, thank you so much! I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Yes, you're right! I missed that. Hopefully you can adjust that last thing yourself.